# Expanding viewbox to get more drawing area and SVG is NOT scaling back down to fit container

Tags: html, css, svg, styled-components

I have this svg element that I need to be renderend on screen as:

```
width: 1200px;
height: 400px;
```

It's a chart I and would like to work with a bigger "art board".

I mean, I would like to draw my shapes in a space of `12000 x 4000 units`.

What I've got:

```
LS.Chart_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 1200px;
  height: 400px;
`;

LS.Chart_SVG = styled.svg`
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

```
RETURN STATEMENT

<LS.Chart_DIV>
  <LS.Chart_SVG viewbox="0 0 1200 400" ref={svgElement_ref}>
    {lineItems}
    {barItems}
  </LS.Chart_SVG>
</LS.Chart_DIV>
```

With the code above I'm being able to draw the chart using a 1200x400 coordenates. But I have many elements, and to draw inside that space I will end up using decimals. For example: a width for one of my shapes will be 1.2 points, instead of 12 (this is what I would get if I'm able to expand my drawing space 10 times to 12000 x 4000).

If try I change the code to:

```
RETURN STATEMENT

<LS.Chart_DIV>
  <LS.Chart_SVG viewbox="0 0 12000 4000" ref={svgElement_ref}>
    {lineItems}
    {barItems}
  </LS.Chart_SVG>
</LS.Chart_DIV>
```

I draw my shapes on this new reference (12000 x 4000). It works (but it turns GIANT on screen and doesn't fit my 1200px x 400px div at all. I.E: it's not scaling down. I thought that viewBox attribute would automatically scale down the svg to fit the container.

How can I fix this?

NOTE: This markup is because I'm using `styled-components`. In the end `<LS.Chart_DIV>` is a `<div>` and `<LS.Chart_SVG>` is an `<svg>`.

Answer (score 0):

It DOES automatically scale up and down.

The bug was a typo on `viewbox` when it was supposed to be `viewBox`, with a capital **B**.

Now it's fixed.

```
RETURN STATEMENT

<LS.Chart_DIV>
  <LS.Chart_SVG viewBox="0 0 12000 4000" ref={svgElement_ref}>
    {lineItems}
    {barItems}
  </LS.Chart_SVG>
</LS.Chart_DIV>
```